# JDK 1.8 not working with IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2 "Error: Abnormal build process termination"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, ide, heap-memory

I know I am probably the *n*th person asking this question, but I have been trying to hunt down a solution for this by looking at other answers for the past couple of days but I am still stuck.

Whenever I try to use **JDK 1.8 with IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2**, I get the following error when I try to run my program:

```
Error: Abnormal build process termination: 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 716800KB object heap
```

I have tried to change the vmoptions, but I still do not have any luck with this. Here are the values I currently have for my vmoptions:

### idea.exe.vmoptions

```
-server
-Xms512m
-Xmx1028m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1028m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

---

### idea64.exe.vmoptions

```
-Xms1028m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1028m -Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1028m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

Any solutions to resolve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have 700MB of RAM available & are you using a 64bit JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came to a solution by changing the vm options to the following:

**idea.exe.vmoptions**

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

---

**idea64.exe.vmoptions**

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. After I added:

```
-Xmx256m
```

to 'VM options', it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because of the

> -server

option included in my idea64.exe.vmoptions.
Try to remove it and restart your IDE